# Panelizer page manager variants not selected

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, panels

I have installed the page manager, panels everywhere and Panelizer. A long time ago I set up a few content types and managed them with Panelizer, it all works fine.
I've made a *site_template* variant, just once at this time and it all works also fine. Now I wan't to make different site templates for different content types.

So I've made a *node_view* "Panelizer"-variant for each content type. I've also made the different *site_templates* variants. Then I select the *site_template* for each *node_view* variant. But it din't work's as I expected it!!

It always tooks the site_template variant at the top and not the selected. It seems that the *node_view* panelizer variant is never selected, because the panelizer overrides the page manager (? !).

Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround.
In the site_template variants i made a selection rule on the node type. Problem was, that i have pages that arent nodes, just simple pages. I cloned the Variants and removed the selection rule. Then i choosed this site_template in de pages.

Now i've got a lot of site_template variants wich is not so nice, but it works.